# MouseLeftButton event doesnt gets triggered when used with Custom Event Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, events, triggers

Have used the event trigger like below,

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <local:EventTriggerExt EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding BuyItemCommand}" />
        </local:EventTriggerExt>
        <local:EventTriggerExt EventName="MouseRightButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SellItemCommand}" />
        </local:EventTriggerExt>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Code Behind:

```
class EventTriggerExt :System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger
{
    protected override void OnEvent(EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if(this.AssociatedObject is SfDataGrid && eventArgs is MouseButtonEventArgs)
        {
            var args = eventArgs as MouseButtonEventArgs;

        }
        base.OnEvent(eventArgs);
    }
}
```

When i click on DataGrid Cell, MouseRightButtonDown event worked well with SellItemCommand. But MouseLeftButtonDown event is not working and also for LeftClick event. Hope any one faced this and suggest a solution for the same.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Smirti

Answer (score 0):

`MouseLeftButtonDown` event will not be fired in case you are clicking on the `DataGrid` cells. This is because `SelectionChanged` event will be called before `MouseLeftButtonDown` and after that it will not bubble the event. If you click on some other part of DataGrid other than cells e.g. the empty space after the last column, you will notice that `MouseLeftButtonDown` is being called.

So instead of '`MouseLeftButtonDown`' you can use `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event which will be called before the `SelectionChanged`.

Comment: PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown is not working in my side. have tried the event Leftclick. it is also not working. any other way?